# How to get the number of login attempts in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.7

Laravel version 5.7 -

I am currently attempting to grab the number of login attempts. The Laravel's documentation does not provide a guide for this. But I think I am getting closer to finding the answer on my own by backtracking all the methods being called.

Anyhow, my goal is to display the number of 'logins attempted / max login attempt' before the lockout.

In Auth\LoginController I can easily get the number of maxAttempts, and even set my preferred number of max attempts:

`protected $maxAttempts = 3;`

Great. So I create a function to get login attempt details:

```
public function getCurrentAttempts() {
    $limiter = $this->limiter();

    $login_attempts = array(
        // gets the number of current login attempted
        'currentAttempts' => $limiter->hit('user'),

        // get the number of max attempts allowed
        'maxAttempts' => $this->maxAttempts(),

        // return 1 or 0 if current login attempts reached max attempts
        'locked' => $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts('user', $this->maxAttempts())
    );

    return view('auth.login')->withLoginAttempts(
        $login_attempts
    );
}
```

Please note:

`$this->limiter()->hit(key)` <<< expects a key. I really don't know what kind of key it is expecting. Help anyone? I typed 'user', and for some reason is sending me back the correct number of attempts. But is this correct? Is that the 'key' that `$limiter->hit()` is expecting? Doesn't the 'key' has something to do with Request?

Other things to note:
Nicely enough, from the LoginController I can easily get the $maxAttempts value by simply `$this->maxAttempts()`, that's really nice. But what about the number of current login attempts? Wouldn't it be ideal to have it in the same place? That's what I am trying to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the Laravel docs several times, I began to try various classes already built in within the framework that allowed me to achieve my goal (getting the current number of login attempts)

In the LoginController we must `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` and then by method injection, the `Request $request` can be captured in the method.

I was then able to get the 'throttleKey', which is the key that I needed like so:
In the LoginController's method body, `$this->limiter()->hit($this->throttleKey($request));`

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for exactly for that! In my case to get the number of attempts left: `$nb_attempts_left = $this->limiter()->retriesLeft($this->throttleKey($request), $this->maxAttempts); `

Answer (score 0):

El Sordo's answer worked for me, but I found a slightly cleaner way to do this.

First, use RateLimiter in the LoginController namespace:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;`

Then you can get the number of login attempts like this:

`RateLimiter::attempts($this->throttleKey($request))`

In my case I also had to use ThrottlesLogins in the LoginController class, otherwise I could not call the throttleKey method from $this, which references the current class/object.

`use ThrottlesLogins;`